# Is there a suggested format or approach in TraMineR for sequences with 300+ events in length?

Tags: sequence, traminer

I am dealing with time stamped event sequences that are 300+ events long. This data is similar to web logs, where users hit different pages of a website at different times. One sequence may be one web session and each event is a user action (visit page, click button, etc).

I first used the TSE format. When trying to find subsequences using seqefsub() TraMineR hung. I set maxk = 5 and it worked (this limits the length of subsequences to be searched for to 5 events). However, maxK 6 or higher also hangs. Not sure why this sudden drop off. Also, when I pruned the event sequences to only be 15 events in length everything completed fine. So clearly event sequence length is an issue here.

Is there a different format that is more robust to sequence length, e.g. STS? Are there any other recommendations for dealing with sequences of this length in TraMineR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the format used to enter the sequences.

`TraMineR` has only a rudimentary algorithm for searching subsequences.

I would suggest you look at more appropriate tools for your problem. Consider for instance the R package  [`arulesSequences`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arulesSequences/index.html).

Comment: The implication being that it deals better with longer sequences? Thanks, I'll give it a try.